# Is there a way to scale in "instance" (part of ASG ) on certain custom metric?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

***I'm using the AutoScalingGroup to launch a group of EC2 instances. These instances are acting as workers which are continuously listening to SQS for any new request.***

**Requirement**: 
Do upscale on something like throughput (i.e Total number of messages present in SQS by total number instances).

And I want to downscale whenever any instance which is part of ASG is sitting idle (CPUIdle) for let's say more than 15 mins.

**Note**: I am not looking for any metric which applies as whole to a particular ASG (eg: Average CPU).

*One way of doing that could be defining the custom metric and allowing it to trigger a cloudwatch alarm to do that.* 
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining the scaling policy at instance level, then you defeating the entire purposes of ASG. If you need to scale based on changing conditions, such as the queue size, then you can configure ASG based on the conditions specified here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html

> A custom metric to send to Amazon CloudWatch that measures the number of messages in the queue per EC2 instance in the Auto Scaling group.
>
> A target tracking policy that configures your Auto Scaling group to scale based on the >custom metric and a set target value. CloudWatch alarms invoke the scaling policy.

If you know a specific time window when the queue size goes up or down, you can also scale based on schedule.

You can always start with a very low instance count in ASG and set the desired capacity as such (say 1) and scale up based on queue, so you can continue using ASG policies.

Comment: "f you are defining the scaling policy at the instance level, then you defeat the entire purposes of ASG. "
I am doing that to handle a large amount of load when the volume of the request is HIGH, and also want to make sure I do not scale in any instance which was still working.

I do not think scaling on a scheduled basis would be the right approach for me as traffic is unpredictable.

Comment: You can always use connection draining feature in auto-scaling to avoid scaling in any instance that is in active use. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-connection-draining-remove-instances-from-service-with-care/